# How to reverse an array using three separate methods in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, reverse

I'm currently going through an ebook in order to learn C# and I am currently at a place where I am stuck. I feel that once I have pushed through and understand this next bit, it will really accelerate my understanding and learning as I move on to classes next.

The current challenge I face I must do the following :

- Make a program that uses methods to reverse an array.
- Create three methods: one to create the array, one to print the array and one to reverse the array.
- Ideally it would allow the user to input the desired length of the array.
- Not allowed to use the reverse array method.

This is the code I have gotten so far but I'm extremely stuck on how to create the reverse method and I feel like what I currently have isn't what is required either. I just need that extra push here for it to click in place and for me to get the understanding I need. Feel free to just positions hints / tips / advice as oppose to the solution if you so wish.

Thank you all.

`using System;`

namespace Using_methods_to_reverse_an_array
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] CreateArray()
        {
            int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            return array;
        }
        static void PrintNumbers()
        {
            foreach (int numbers in CreateArray())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numbers);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = CreateArray();
            PrintNumbers();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

Comment: You should be passing `numbers` to `PrintNumbers`. `PrintNumbers` should not be calling `CreateArray`. You will also have to pass `numbers` to your reversing method once you write it. To reverse the array, you will either need to know how to swap two items, or how to copy the array backwards.

Comment: Thank you kindly for the response, you're absolutely right, I think your comment has greatly helped me with what I need to do next, in particular the fact that you told me PrintNumbers should not be calling CreateArray.

I will have another crack at it and see how I get on, I will check the examples below after I've given it a good go first.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int[] Reverse(int[] arr){
    int [] arr2 = new int[arr.Length];
    for (int i = arr.Length - 1, i2 = 0; i >= 0; i--, i2++)
    {
        arr2[i2] = arr[i];
    }
    return arr2;
}


static void PrintNumbers(int[] arr)
{
  foreach (int numbers in arr)
  {
      Console.WriteLine(numbers);
  }
}

static void Main(){
    int[] arr = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] arr2 = Reverse(arr);
    PrintNumbers(arr2);
}
```

prints

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a ton for the help everyone, after doing some more Googling and tests my final product is this :

```
using System;

namespace Using_methods_to_reverse_an_array
{
    class Program
    {
        static int[] CreateArray()
        {
            int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
            return array;
        }

        static void PrintNumbers(int[] array)
        {
            foreach (int numbers in array )
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numbers);
            }
        }

        static void ReverseNumbers(int[] array)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < array.Length/2; i++)
            {
                int temp = array[i];
                array[i] = array[array.Length - i - 1];
                array[array.Length - i - 1] = temp;
            }

        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = CreateArray();
            ReverseNumbers(numbers);
            PrintNumbers(numbers);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the only thing I need to figure out next is to allow the user to specify the length of the array and then reverse it, as oppose to using pre-defined values. Every time I make the edit, if you enter say "5" it simply prints out 0 five times which is not my intention. Since I got so stuck with this bit I plan to go over it a few more times before I continue in my learning.

Comment: What about the array values? Would that be entered?

Comment: Essentially what I'd want to happen is that the user is able to specify the length of the array. I'm guessing if the user is unable to enter the elements within the array it will simply print 0's? Thanks a lot for all of the help everyone.

Comment: So I guess now you are just 1 step away from completing your project since you have already completed a major part of it, it shouldn't be too difficult for you to do the remaining. Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood, but I think this should do it:

```
    class Program
        {
            static int[] CreateArray()
            {
                int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
                return array;
            }
//I changed this to receive an input array
            static void PrintNumbers( int[] inputArray)
            {
                foreach (int numbers in inputArray)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(numbers);
                }
            }
//this function should reverse any array passed to it
            static void ReverseArray(int[] inputArray)
            {
                int len = inputArray.Length;
                int[] newArray = new int[len];
                foreach (int i in inputArray)
                {
                    newArray[i] = inputArray[len - 1];
                    len--;
                }
            }
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                int[] numbers = CreateArray();
                PrintNumbers(numbers);
                ReverseArray(numbers);
                //Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```